# Is it possible to split the ledger into multiple parts in hyperledger fabric?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, blockchain

1. Is it possible to access the ledger without being a node into the hyperledger fabric network?
2. For example node A and node B are in the same channel, is it possible to split the node A ledger into multiple parts?
   and can we have any one part of the node A ledger is replicated into node B ledger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. No. Hyperledger Fabric is a permissioned network, so if an entity is not a part of the network, it is not able to access the ledger.
2. A solution similar to what you ask can be [done via Private Data](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.3/private-data/private-data.html), where peer A and B being in the same channel, can have data that is hidden from each other (Only the hash of the data is shared) and another part that is only shared between A and B but not C etc.

Comment: 1) not a 'node' - but an organisation, like a regulatory organisation, could be allowed (via application/integration, eg cloud hosted) to access the ledger, without deploying 'infrastructure'  - on 2) No, you wouldn't 'split the ledger' in the fashion you describe and as adnan.c indicates above - you should start with the use case, rather than the semantics of infrastructural dissection. Probably best to read the comprehensive docs page on architectural context -> https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.3/peers/peers.html and understand more on private data collections (above).